# How to delete object using function based view?

Tags: django

I am having trouble trying to implement a delete function-based view as I am unsure of what is the correct syntax.

So far this is the method that I am using:

```py
def delete_lesson(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        lesson = Lesson.objects.get(post_id=request.get('post_id'))
        lesson.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

I have implemented the delete function in my model:

```py
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="lesson/pdf")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lesson_upload', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file.delete()
        self.title.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)



class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default0.jpg', upload_to='course_image/')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})
```

My urls.py:

```
path('post/<int:post_id>/lesson_delete/', views.delete_lesson, name='delete_lesson'),
```

Comment: `Lesson.objects.get(post_id=request.get('post_id'))` should be `Lesson.objects.get(post_id=request.POST.get('post_id'))`.

Comment: why you get 'post_id' in arguments too?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `post_id` in your URL which passes the id to your view which you also received.

So if you want to remove the post with the id in your URL then this is how you can do:

```
lesson = Lesson.objects.get(post_id=post_id)
```

If for any reasons you get a post id from your template and it's different than the post id in your URL, then this is how you should do it:

```
Lesson.objects.get(post_id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
```

Note if you're using the second option which the `post_id` you want to delete is different than what you have in `post/<int:post_id>/lesson_delete/` then you should pass the `post_id` as a POST data from your template.

Comment: when I changed it to:

lesson = Lesson.objects.get(post_id=post_id)

it gives me TypeError: delete_lesson() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_id'

any idea what is the issue? right now I am trying to delete the uploaded file based on the primary key of my Post model.

Comment: should I be using Lesson_id instead if i want to delete the specific Lesson file that is being uploaded?

Comment: It depends but in general YES.